# The 1st element doesn't get sorted during insertion sort

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() 
{

    int a[6] = {5,2,4,6,1,3};
    int j,i,k,cnt=1;
    for (j=1;j<7;j++)
    {
        k = a[j];
        i = j-1;
        while(i>0 && a[i]>k)
        {
            a[i+1] = a[i];
            i = i-1;
        }
        a[i+1] = k;
    }
    for(i=0;i<6;i++) 
    {
        printf("\n Final op %d",a[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

I am passing some elements in a static array but the 1st element that's value

`a[0]` is not getting sorted but rest of the values from `a[1]` to `a[5]` gets sorted

Comment: Notice that your use of `a[j]` when `j` is 6 causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @phresnel: I think that's how an illiterate spells "don't know why".

Comment: I believe "donno y" is meant to be "I don't know why". I'll edit it out of the title.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Oh, I see. To be totally honest, and I don't mean to be rude, really just honest, it looks stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(i>-1 && a[i]>k)
        {
           a[i+1] = a[i];
           i = i-1;
        }
```

make only this change and your insertion sort will work perfectly.

its not getting sorted because array starts from a[0] n your while gets terminated when its at a[0] so not visiting its element.

hope it helped you

Comment: I'd argue it won't work "perfectly" as long as the code keeps accessing `a[6]`.

Comment: @Troubadour, Sure it does! Then, only when you need to do something really important on it, will your computer blow up.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `>0` in

```
while(i>0
```

This should read

```
while(i>=0
```

Also, there's undefined behaviour in

```
    k = a[j];
```

when `j==6`.

Comment: I prefer this to i > -1, but that's just taste.